# Average data for hours in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to obtain the average data for hours in a query but with a clause for column. I tried this:

```
SELECT  DATEPART(hour, Fecha) as Hora, CONVERT(INT, AVG(particulas))as PARTICULAS
from filtro1
where flag1 ='0' and fecha >= '16-03-2020 17:20:00.370' and fecha <= '17-03-2020 06:20:00.370' GROUP 
BY DATEPART(hour, Fecha)
Union 
SELECT  DATEPART(hour, Fecha) as Hora ,AVG(presion) AS PRESION
from filtro1
where flag2 ='0' and fecha >= '16-03-2020 17:20:00.370' and fecha <= '17-03-2020 06:20:00.370' 
GROUP BY DATEPART(hour, Fecha)
ORDER BY Hora
```

But the result is this:

[image]

I need the result in differents columns but with the same hour row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT DATEPART(hour, Fecha) AS Hora, 
       AVG(CASE WHEN FLAG1 = 0 THEN particulas END) AS PARTICULAS, 
       AVG(CASE WHEN FLAG2 = 0 THEN presion END) AS PRESION
FROM filtro1
WHERE fecha >= '2020-03-16 17:20:00.370' AND
      fecha <= '2020-03-17 06:20:00.370' AND
      0 IN (FLAG1, FLAG2)
GROUP BY DATEPART(hour, Fecha);
```

Comment: no, i need  the avg result from particulas where have flag1 = 0 and the avg result from presion where have flag2 = 0, they are diferents columns flag1 and flag2

Comment: @mourazo. . . I forgot to mentioned condition.

Comment: Hi, but this is the average of all data i need the data average only  where flags = 0

Comment: @mourazo. . . Add one more condition with where clause. Check edited.

Comment: @mourazo . . . I don't think this produces the correct answers.  I would suggest that you double check the results.

Answer (score 0):

- Make a query that returns both data cells in SEPARATE ROWS.
- Wrap them in a PIVOT statement that creates a projection that moves them into separate rows.

Pivot is a little gem but likely hardly anyone knows it. Requires decently current version of SQL Server.

Syntax in the manual. I am on the go now and have no time to look up the details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want accurate values for the the averages, then you need `NULL` values for the non-matches.  ININaddition, you should use proper date formats:

```
SELECT DATEPART(hour, Fecha) AS Hora, 
       AVG(CASE WHEN FLAG1 = 0 THEN particulas END) AS PARTICULAS, 
       AVG(CASE WHEN FLAG2 = 0 THEN presion END) AS PRESION
FROM filtro1
WHERE fecha >= '2020-03-16 17:20:00.370' AND
      fecha <= '2020-03-17 06:20:00.370' AND
      0 IN (FLAG1, FLAG2)
GROUP BY DATEPART(hour, Fecha)
ORDER BY MIN(Fecha);
```